# Desenvolvimento mobile multiplataforma

Tags: javascript, html, css, mobile

Sou desenvolvedor .Net (MVC, WPF, MCF) e preciso desenvolver um projeto *mobile* multi-plataforma, fiz uma pesquisa e verifiquei que existem diversos *framework's* que resolvem a questão como PhoneGap, Apache Cordova, Ionic, Lungo entre outros.

Verifiquei que a maioria dos *framework's* são baseados em HTML, CSS e JavaScript.

Qual desses *framework's* possui a **melhor desempenho** e **menor curva de aprendizado**?

Comment: Esta pergunta está a ser discutida no meta: http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/3975/porque-%C3%A9-que-acham-que-esta-pergunta-%C3%A9-baseada-em-opini%C3%B5es

Comment: Olá Luã! Bem-vindo ao [pt.so]! Como o Jorge já comentou, sua pergunta está sendo discutida pela comunidade. Achamos ela interessante, porém do jeito atual não parece ser possível dar uma resposta que não seja estritamente opinativa (por razões que eu expliquei no meta). Seria possível definir melhor na sua pergunta quais são as características e requisitos do projeto que precisa desenvolver? Por exemplo, dependendo do projeto, pode ser que a diferença de desempenho entre as bibliotecas seja insignificante.